# Get data from server url using php

Tags: php

how to get data from my server url which include these json data. I have use api like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>_checksmsfrom</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://cc.frifon.net/_checksmsfrom/" method="post">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>SIP</td>
        <td><input name="sip" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UUID</td>
        <td><input name="uuid" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PWD</td>
        <td><input name="pwd" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>To</td>
        <td><input name="to" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Since</td>
        <td><input name="since" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key<br>
        </td>
        <td><input readonly="readonly" name="key" value="190qopAKL"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the json data display out like this :

```
{"status":0,"message":[["60146600472","##IMAGE##showpic.php?file=1380253368Cars 4 Ford Mustang Classic.jpg##IMAGE##","1380253368"],["60134194410","Gdgdgd","1380789783"],["60134194410","Gdgdtst","1380789810"],["60134194410","Ghdgdhdgdgdtdtdgdg","1380789834"],["60134194410","Tdtdsgdgdgdgdgs","1380789840"],["60134194410","Gdgdgxfhbhgjgu hvhfh \n Hdhcbch\n Jfjvjv. Jgmbkb\n Jbjbjbjbj","1380789862"],["60134194410","Ggdgdg","1381139453"],["60134194410","Ffhfdet","1381389492"],["60146600472","assadasa sad","1382434816"],["60146600472","sdasdsad","1382441655"],["60146600472","cubaaaaaaaa","1382493484"]],"read":["1380253368"]}
```

so how can I display or parse this json data in an array into my webpage . please im stuck at this for couple of weeks.

Comment: This is very confusing. Do you want to JSON encode the data POST'ed or what?

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.2.0, there is a function called `json_encode()` that takes any organized data and encodes it properly for you.

Simply post your form to a page that will do something like this:

```
                        $res = array();
                        $res["code"] = 200;
                        $res["message"] = "OK";
                        $res["companies"] = array("Coca-Cola", "Apple")
```

And then print that output:

`echo json_encode($res)`

In example, that will give you:

```
{"code":200,"message":"OK","companies":[Coca-Cola, Apple]}
```

Modify accordingly.

Though to be honest I don't know why you would post to a page like that. Requests like these are usually given by the server and not the user. Do what you need to do, I guess.

EDIT:

If you need, you can decode a request too. Use `json_decode()` if your form is sending a generated JSON request. Not that I would recommend doing that with a POST form, but again, do what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Andy . Actually what I want to do is to parse that json data in an array into my web page. what I need to do is calling the server url and it will output the data given.